# Angular Google Map version 3.0 beta disable zoom controls and street view controls

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am upgrading **Angular Google Maps** (AGM) version from 1.0.0-beta.5 to 3.0.0-beta.0
In version 1.0 **agm-map** had attributes **zoomControl** and **streetViewControl**.

```
<agm-map [zoomControl]="false" [streetViewControl]="false">
</agm-map>
```

However, in version 3.0 these attributes have been removed so I can't disable the zoom or street view controls in the map.
I notice there are directives **AgmZoomControl** and **AgmStreetViewControl**:
https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmzoomcontrol
https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmstreetviewcontrol

But there are no examples on how to use them or whether they can be used to disable the controls.
Anyone know how I can disable zoom controls and street view controls in AGM version 3.0?

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: these paraeters are still valid & working with the beta version [streetViewControl]="false" [zoomControl]="false"

Comment: Try with deleting @agm/core from node_modules and reinstall @agm/core again.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but if you're on Angular9+ I'd suggest dropping AGM and going for the official component for Google Maps (@angular/google-maps). You can read more about it here: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, zoomControl and streetViewControl definitely do not exist for @agm/core 3.0.0-beta.0. Yes, I saw that article from Tim Deschryver on the official Angular google-map component. However, I need the input autocomplete feature that is supported with @agm/core. Is it possible to do this with the google-map component? I could not find any iinformation for this anywhere. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This comes with their default UI view you can disable it by adding a property.
Hopefully, it will work.

```
<agm-map [disableDefaultUI]='true'>
```

Comment: This works for the street view control but no for the zoom.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
<agm-map
    [latitude]="lat"
    [longitude]="lng"
    [zoom]="15"
    [maxZoom]="15"
    [minZoom]="15"
    [disableDefaultUI]="true">
</agm-map>
```

You have to set the default zoom, max zoom and min zoom.